# Disable certificate check in Hudson when using Release plugin

Tags: svn, ssl, jenkins, hudson

I'm trying to use the Maven Release Plugin in Hudson. When I perform a Release I get the following error:

```
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://servername/svn/project/trunk/testapp': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://servername)
```

We are using a self signed certificate.

I've tried several things:

1. Do a `svn list` as the user running the build
2. Added a `svn-settings.xml` to `~/.scm` with: `trustServerCert` set to true

None of these things resolved the issue. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I know about these options, but I don't know how to add them to the Jenkins/Hudson CLI. What I found was that some use a script to fetch updates from SVN and add these options. This is not what I want/what will work for us.

Answer (score 1):

The way i solved it was:

1. Logged into the server (command line - SSH)
2. Executed a plain svn checkout:

   ```
     svn checkout https://someserverwithinvalidcertificate
     Error validating server certificate for 'https://someserverwithinvalidcertificate:443':
     - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
      fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
   Certificate information:
    - Hostname: someserverwithinvalidcertificate
    - Valid: from Jul  1 12:14:08 2013 GMT until Jul  1 12:14:08 2014 GMT
    - Issuer: ???, ????, ????, ????, ??
    - Fingerprint: fb:44:5a:80:......c8:b0:8b:2f:d8:c4
   (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? p
   svn: OPTIONS of 'https://someserverwithinvalidcertificate': 200 OK               (https://someserverwithinvalidcertificate)
   ```

After i accepted the certificate permanently, the hudson release executed without any problem.